# clickable <article> background color

Tags: html, css

I'm (trying) to set up a simple blog template using HTML5/CSS3, with posts being handles using the  tag.

I would like to have each post 'clickable' in order to get to its 'read more' page. I found that I could put the anchor tag  either inside or outside the article:

```
<a href="#"> <article> .... </article> </a>
```

or:

```
<article> <a href="#"> .... </a> </article>
```

both seems to work (btw: which way is preferable?).

my question is how to set up the CSS so that the background-color will change when I hover the (clickable) post ?

thanks in advance,
 Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
article {
    background-color:red;
}

article:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K8XpM/1/)

as for your side question, it will work both ways, but its better for seo for the  tag to be inside the article tag.

Comment: thanks - works!but then only the text within the <article> is clickable, and not the entire post area.. how can i fix that?

Comment: @user2389917 see my updated fiddle.  I just set the link to display:block and set the width to 100% which forces it to fill the article container.  you can also do that with the height depending on what else you have inside the <article> tag

Comment: thanks - almost there! so, I have some padding within the article container: article {
    background-color:red;
    overflow: hidden;
 line-height: 25px;
    padding: 10% 10%;
},  and the padded zone does not link.. any idea?

Comment: put the padding on the <a> instead

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the main question: if the link is wrapping the article you can use `a:hover{background-color: red;}`.

If the article is not being wrapped, you can use `article:hover{background-color: red;}`.

As far as which is preferable, it is really a matter of opinion I think. That being said, an anchor tag is an inline element and therefore cannot contain a block element if you wish to use valid html.